# Is there a way to use a webservice for `createrawtransaction`?

Tags: websites, bitcoin-cli, createrawtransaction

[createrawtransaction](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#createrawtransaction) is a bitcoin-cli command that generates a raw transaction given one or more transaction ids and a list of `Outputs`, which are the destination amounts that will receive the funds.

AFAIK, the raw transaction is only based on the blockchain, and does not require any private key or address; the signing process is done separately, using [`signrawtransaction`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#signrawtransaction).

**If the `createrawtransaction` process requires no secret keys, is there a way to generate a raw transaction online, using a web service?**

Comment: createrawtransaction is not based on anything. It just converts the arguments you are passing to a hex transaction. It does not need a network connection, or the blockchain, or your wallet. There is even a standalone tool shipped with bitcoind (bitcoin-tx) that can do the same. Why do you need a webservice for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, a private key is not required to use `createrawtransaction`. The private key is only required during the signing process of `signrawtransaction` just as you stated in your question.

If you are looking for a web service that will allow you to create a raw transaction online, I suggest you check out http://coinb.in it does exactly this, as well as broadcast the transaction, and allow you to save a local copy to sign the transaction offline.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a step by step tutorial from create wallet to broadcast a transaction in testnet with online tools : [step-by-step-create-and-broadcast-a-bitcoin-transaction-on-testnet](https://medium.com/@athamidn/estep-by-step-create-and-broadcast-a-bitcoin-transaction-on-testnet-588daacc2b7a?source=friends_link&sk=2c9a310c02801d09c667608d4651e80f)